# how can i manage two column chart width without keeping gap in series?

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I am trying to keep chart bar with two column series like series should not keep gap in that and same bar width should also constant.
**Image for reference.**  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdP0W.png)..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FL9OJ.png)

i have tried it with   pointWidth:30, and i was creating gap between series but remove gap i have tried  groupPadding: 0.32, but it is breaking whenever we are changing  window size and in mobile screen..

```
{
  "chart": {
    "style": {
      "fontFamily": "Arial"
    },
    "type": "column",
    "animation": false
  },
  "title": {
    "text": ""
  },
  "legend": {
    "enabled": true,
    "symbolRadius": 2,
    "margin": 0,
    "itemHoverStyle": {
      "color": "#000"
    },
    "itemHiddenStyle": {
      "color": "#cccccc"
    }
  },
  "credits": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "series": [{
    "type": "column",
    "pointPlacement": 0.2,
    "name": "Series1",
    "turboThreshold": 4,
    "data": [{
      "name": "abcd",
      "y": 123.5

    }],
    "minPointLength": 3
  }, {
    "type": "column",
    "pointPlacement": 0.2,
    "name": "Series2",
    "turboThreshold": 1,
    "data": [{
      "name": "abcd",
      "y": 15.2
    }],
    "minPointLength": 3
  }],
  "plotOptions": {
    "series": {
      "animation": false,
      "events": {}
    },
    "column": {
      "pointPadding": 0,
      "groupPadding": 0.3,
      "borderWidth": 0,
      "borderRadius": 2
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure if I fully understand your requirements. Could you please clarify once again? You can also provide an example image that shows what you would like to achieve. Thanks in advance!


Hello, I'm not sure if I fully understand your requirements. Could you please clarify once again? You can also provide an example image that shows what you would like to achieve. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @magdalena
i kept requirement picture in my question.
please have look. In that picture column chart height should be not increase more and column gap should not be there

Comment: Apologize, but your case description is not clear for me. I created a demo example with using pointRagne, could you please tell if its fits to your requirements https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7rhcgmbq/?